# How to properly stop thread in class when the class is exposed to QML

Tags: multithreading, qt, qml, signals-slots

I have a class that is exposed to QML:

qmlRegisterType("SerialThread", 1, 0, "SerialThread");

This class inherits QThread and the QThread.start() is called from QML.

When the user closes the application, how do I properly exit the thread before the program terminates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the destructor, you should call `quit()` followed by `wait()`. Since, hopefully, you've made QML own the thread object, it will destruct it - feel free to verify that the destructor is, in fact, executed.

If you don't spin an event loop in the thread, then you must reimplement `quit()` to set your own stop flag. Since you hide the underlying non-virtual `quit()`, your "thread" is not really a `QThread` anymore, and you *must* inherit from `QThread` privately - it's a semantic error to do otherwise (and leads to bad bugs).

How such bugs happen? Since you can pass your "not quite" a thread somewhere a `QThread` is expected, those users of it are free to assume it's a real thread, not a "not quite one", and call `QThread::quit()` method, which is a no-op without an event loop. Thus bugs.

To maintain [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), if you need to override non-virtual public methods, you must privately inherit from the parent class, since it's not usable in places where its parent would be usable.

```
class MyThread : private QThread {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(MyThread)
  volatile bool m_stop;
  void run() { ... }
public:
  MyThread(QObject * parent = nullptr) : QThread(parent) { ... }
  void quit() { m_stop = true; }
  // It's important to fully qualify the Priority type, otherwise moc will generate
  // wrong code.
  Q_SLOT void start(QThread::Priority priority = InheritPriority) {
    if (isRunning()) return;
    m_stop = false;
    QThread::start();
  }
  using QThread::isRunning;
  using QThread::isFinished;
  bool isInterruptionRequested() const { return m_stop; }
  ~MyThread() {
    quit();
    wait();
  }
  // Publicly we're only a QObject, not a thread
  operator QObject&() { return *this; }
  operator const QObject&() const { return *this; }
  void run() {
    while (!m_stop) { ... }
  }
};
```

Comment: Confirmed that the destructor is called. Had to re-implement quit(). Thanks!

Comment: @Phataas Make sure that you inherit privately from QThread, etc., as shown in the example code above. Reimplementing quit(), a *non-virtual method*, makes your "thread" not really a QThread.

Answer (score 0):

You can call thread.stop() and check thread.isRunning() before returning exit value in the main.

Comment: How do I get access to the object "SerialThread" which is exposed to QML only?